# Kohana ORM: Array to string conversion Error

Tags: php, orm, kohana

I tried using Kohana/ORM on my localhost xampp and i get the following error

ErrorException [ Notice ]: Array to string conversion
MODPATH\orm\classes\kohana\orm.php [ 980 ]

```
975             }
976             else
977             {
978                 // List columns and mirror for performance
979                 $this->_table_columns = $this->list_columns();
980                 $this->_table_columns = array_combine($this->_table_columns, $this->_table_columns);
981 
982                 // Load column cache
983                 ORM::$_column_cache[$this->_object_name] = $this->_table_columns;
984             }
985         }
```

It seems to be a common error appearing in different Frameworks/PHP Applications, but I have not found any clue to fix it.

The Model is just the basic ORM

```
class Model_Product extends ORM {

}
```

The Mysql Table (InnoDB - UTF-8) has two fields
id - primary int
name - varchar 50

no voodoo anywhere, help is very appreciated

thanks in advance!

edit: the requested vardump

```
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  array(13) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "int"
    ["min"]=>
    string(11) "-2147483648"
    ["max"]=>
    string(10) "2147483647"
    ["column_name"]=>
    string(2) "id"
    ["column_default"]=>
    NULL
    ["data_type"]=>
    string(3) "int"
    ["is_nullable"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["ordinal_position"]=>
    int(1)
    ["display"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["extra"]=>
    string(14) "auto_increment"
    ["key"]=>
    string(3) "PRI"
    ["privileges"]=>
    string(31) "select,insert,update,references"
  }
  ["name"]=>
  array(12) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "string"
    ["column_name"]=>
    string(4) "name"
    ["column_default"]=>
    NULL
    ["data_type"]=>
    string(7) "varchar"
    ["is_nullable"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["ordinal_position"]=>
    int(2)
    ["character_maximum_length"]=>
    string(2) "50"
    ["collation_name"]=>
    string(15) "utf8_general_ci"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["extra"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["key"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["privileges"]=>
    string(31) "select,insert,update,references"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the `var_dump($this->list_columns())` to your question.

Comment: what is the version you are using?

Comment: the newest directly from github, added both kohana and orm as submodules

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this, @rootman? Someone is having a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16694548/472495), just wondering if it is/was a PHP bug? I see your Kohana bug report was closed as invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to resolve this error, just declare the table colums in the model.

```
protected $_table_columns = array(
    'column' => NULL,
    'names'  => NULL,
    'go'     => NULL,
    'here'   => NULL,
    ......
);
```

this will ged rid of the problem and increase performance as well.

Answer (score 1):

Line 980:

```
980                 $this->_table_columns = array_combine($this->_table_columns, $this->_table_columns);
```

looks superfluous taken the previous line 979 into account:

```
979                 $this->_table_columns = $this->list_columns();
```

Merging two times the same array is useless, especially as the array is this:

```
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  array(13) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "int"
    ["min"]=>
    string(11) "-2147483648"
    ["max"]=>
    string(10) "2147483647"
    ["column_name"]=>
    string(2) "id"
    ["column_default"]=>
    NULL
    ["data_type"]=>
    string(3) "int"
    ["is_nullable"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["ordinal_position"]=>
    int(1)
    ["display"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["extra"]=>
    string(14) "auto_increment"
    ["key"]=>
    string(3) "PRI"
    ["privileges"]=>
    string(31) "select,insert,update,references"
  }
  ["name"]=>
  array(12) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "string"
    ["column_name"]=>
    string(4) "name"
    ["column_default"]=>
    NULL
    ["data_type"]=>
    string(7) "varchar"
    ["is_nullable"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["ordinal_position"]=>
    int(2)
    ["character_maximum_length"]=>
    string(2) "50"
    ["collation_name"]=>
    string(15) "utf8_general_ci"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["extra"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["key"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["privileges"]=>
    string(31) "select,insert,update,references"
  }
}
```

It only contains string keys. You should open a bug report with the kohana framework.

Comment line 980 until this get's fixed.

Comment: you are right, the line is just ... useless, however a second error pops up when doing this, same kind of error but this time in line 931: $values = array_combine($this->_table_columns, array_fill(0, count($this->_table_columns), NULL)); I guess I will report this issue to kohana and see what they can do

Comment: The problem with such superfluous looking lines is that they contain some archeological information and - as you can see - hide flaws. From what you describe, `$this->_table_columns` does not contain an array under some circumstances. As one is expected I would hardly bail out in line 980  `if (!is_array($this->_table_columns)) throw new UnexpectedValueException('Not an array');` - You will then get a fatal error instead of a notice but it prevents to leave the application in an undefined state. It might also help to find what's causing this through the backtrace.

Comment: I've created an issue at http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/4352 . I think it's an issue that should be addressed asap because it prevents further development if you don't want to tinker around in core files.

Comment: You could look which part of your code triggers that. It might be a flaw in the Kohana codebase, but the cause of it might be in your code. And I won't consider it urgent. I meant urgent is really urgent, no need to create hype around something that is just a flaw related to input validation. Additionally it would be nice if you can actually find the cause of the problem. This helps to fix the bug finally.

Comment: Well the thing is that I just call the model by ORM::factory('product') and it breaks everything. To be honest I have never used a Bugtracker before so urgent might be the wrong choice, I just thought it's an important bug. I'll try to find the cause though and try to offer a fix

Comment: Every bug report is important, by itself. The importance level is often used by the project itself to create a list which bugs to fix first. Sure from a user perspective, the one bug that oneself reports is always most urgent ;), so sure this is subjective. But as far as the bugtracker goes, these fields are often managed by the project. For your bugreport I would add the code which triggers the notice, so others can reproduce the issue. That's often important with issues: how to reproduce? Reproduceable bugs are good bugs, too ;)